# Site Guest User and Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, sharing-rule, guest-user

I'm working with a Flow and Site guest user. I understand that there are some changes that came out that are preventing `Site Guest Users(SGU)` from accessing objects and flows in Winter 21'.

The scenario I have is all the objects are custom. The `SGU` has access to all custom objects in the profile, that are in the flow, but cannot access these records in the flow irrespective of if this is in the community.

Here is the architecture of the

`Contact` ---< `GrandParentObject__c` ---< `ParentObject__c` ---< `ChildObject__c` (need access to this one in the flow).

When the flow runs it's lookups, it can't find the record. Even when I run it from a TestClass context, the records are not visible in APEX either or the Flows. But when run in either context as a System Admin, I can see the records. I'm assuming this is a permissions issue, but not sure how to configure it.

Thanks,

Comment: have you looked here? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_secure_guest_user_sharing.htm&type=5

Comment: I've read that, but I noticed that the enforce secure record access is not checked. Going to test checking that box and see if it does anything with the sharing rule.

Comment: @cropredy it's active. But the sharing rule doesn't appear to be giving the `SGU` access to child records. It's parent record is Public/readWrite

Comment: what about the Account? If the Contact has no Account then it is private so that would be the answer. If not then SGU needs access to the Account as well.

Comment: @ddeve i'll have to give that a shot. I'll post here with the results.